# Creating a custom bundle without NSDocument

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle, nsdocument

I'm trying to implement a bundle document type in to my application. However, after a bit of research it appears that NSDocument is not suitable for what I am trying to do. Essentially, I want to be able to read and write bundles and use them in a modular fashion. The reason why I think I can't use NSDocument is that it seems to want to make a window for every bundle opened, which isn't possible because I may have more than a dozen.

I've tried to do it manually but I can't find any documentation other than the few sentences in the Apple Docs which say to make a folder with NSFileManager. When I make a folder with an extension, for example '.xyz', nothing happens. I read about Uniform Type Identifiers but I can't seem to find how to set a file/folders UTI. Here is the document definition from my Info.plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>xyz</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>icon_128x128.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Test Bundle</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.test.xyz</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I found a way how to set a folder as a bundle, by setting the bundle bit, but it seems rather hacky. [How do I flag a folder as being a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756385/how-do-i-flag-a-folder-as-being-a-package)

Comment: I don't understand why you say `NSDocument` isn't suitable?  Isn't it usual to have a window open for each open "document" (regardless of whether the "document" is a bundle or a normal file)?

Comment: Well, in short I'm wanting to load special widgets comprising of multiple files, hence the bundles. However, the widgets are loaded as an iframe in HTML, hence a window would be useless.

Comment: What worked for me was to remove the `LSItemContentTypes` property (see [here](http://paulsolt.com/blog/2012/02/creating-nsdocument-using-folder-bundles-and-uti-identifiers)).