# iOS Dropbox API : how to tell folders from file packages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox iOS API v2. When trying to sort out folders from files, files that are packages (i.e. a preferences file, or xcodeproject file, .framework, etc.) show up as folder types.  Is there a way to distinguish between folders and file packages?

```
DBFILESMetadata * metaData = ...;
if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFileMetadata class]]) {
    // is a file
} else if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFolderMetadata class]]) {
    // is a folder or file package
} else if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESDeletedMetadata class]]) {
    // has been deleted
}
```

Comment: One thought is that if it has a file extension, then it is not a folder.  That may be good enough for this situation.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/iOS-how-to-tell-folder-from-file-packages/m-p/213188 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with.

```
DBFILESMetadata * metaData = ...;
if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFileMetadata class]]) {
    // is a file
} else if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFolderMetadata class]]) {
    if ([[metaData.name pathExtension] isEqualToString:@""] == NO) {
        // is a file package / bundle
    } else {
        // is a folder 
    }
} else if ([metaData isKindOfClass:[DBFILESDeletedMetadata class]]) {
    // has been deleted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 'bundle' (B) bit is set, then it should be treated as a bundle, rather than a single file.  However, not all 'packages' are 'bundles'.

See:  [How do I flag a folder as being a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756385/how-do-i-flag-a-folder-as-being-a-package)

If the package is used by an app that is installed on the device, then its extension should be registered in the system by that application to identify it as being a package folder rather than a plain folder.  However, I'm not sure if you can identify these as packages from an app that does not have that particular type registered.

See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html

If the package is not a bundle and has an extension that is not registered by an app installed on the current device, then I don't think there is any method that can be certain to be accurate, and your work around of has-a-filename-extension is probably the only thing you can do.

Comment: Interesting!  Do you have a code example for checking the bundle bit, rather than setting?